# CDaoDatabase assertion error

Tags: c++, ms-access, mfc

```
CString m_strRemorcaNmb; // value for this string is set before 
CString path = "DB\\dataBase";
CDaoDatabase db;
try
{
    db.Open(path, 0, 0, "");
    CDaoRecordset rs(&db);
    rs.Open(AFX_DAO_USE_DEFAULT_TYPE, _T("SELECT Numar_inmatriculare FROM Masini;"), 0);

    COleVariant searched(m_strRemorcaNmb); 
    BOOL bFound = rs.Seek("=",&searched);
}
```

Here i try to verify if a CString value is contained in my data base (.mdb). When it reaches `BOOL bFound = rs.Seek("=",&searched);` a `debug assertion failed` error is thrown. Hitting retry on the dialog box the application triggers a breakpoint in `daocore.cpp` at this line `ASSERT(m_nOpenType == dbOpenTable);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `Seek` you have to have a table-type recordset. (See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k3tkt1zd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) To get this, you have to specify the type when you open the recordset.

Example:

```
rs.Open(CDaoRecordSet::dbOpenTable,"table1");
```

This way of checking, if a specific record exists, is very slow. You suck all the records over the network and then check them. It is way better to modify the filter of the recordset before opening, and then check if any records have been returned.

Method A:

```
sql = "SELECT count(*) AS xyz FROM table WHERE Field='value'";
rs.Open(CDaoRecordset::dbOpenSnapshot,sql);
COleVariant count = rs.GetFieldValue(0);
```

Method B for generated recordsets:

```
rs.m_strFilter.Format("Field = '%s'", value);
rs.Open(CDaoRecordset::dbOpenSnapshot,"table");

if(rs.IsEOF()) // no records returned
{
}
```

Comment: I've tried both methods, but none worked for me. Method A: it throws a `debug assertion failed` error, with breakpoint on `ASSERT(m_nFields > 0);` in `daocore.cpp`. I took a record from the table and should have find it at least once. Method B: throws a `CDaoException` saying `Too few parameters. Expected 1.` I used the exact code you provided, changed only the names for table and columns.

Comment: Method A: `CString sql = "SELECT count(*) AS Numar_inmatriculare FROM Masini WHERE Field='m_strRemorcaNmb'";
  rs.Open(dbOpenSnapshot, sql, dbReadOnly);
  COleVariant count = rs.GetFieldValue(0);`

Comment: Method B: `rs.m_strFilter.Format("Field = '%s'", m_strRemorcaNmb);
  rs.Open(dbOpenSnapshot, "Masini");

  if (rs.IsEOF())
  {
   
  }`

Comment: Method A: you are searching for the fixed value 'm_strRemorcaNmb' - I don't think you want this.

Comment: Method B: is your field name 'Field' ?

Comment: You are right. For both methods i forgot to replace `field` with my table's field. It works now for both! `m_strRemNmb` does not have a fix value, as i mentioned in my question, it is set before the query, in an edit box. Thanks you for helping me!